# dynamic fixed height for grid view in flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-layout

I need a 2*2 GridView which always take as much height as it needed to display the 2*2 grid. but the problem is that I have to specify a fixed height which cause undesired layout / scrolling.

Comment: DUP of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58248510/flutter-non-scrollable-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your `GridView` in some `Expanded` widget and use

> shrinkWrap: true,

in `GridView` attribute .

So the `GridView` will wrap to the `Expanded` height.

Do not forget to change settings about `scrolls`.