# How to give flexible height to GridView in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, gridview, height

I cannot use Expanded widget, thats why using some calculating for creating flexible height. But in some phone models it works fine but some of them it doesn't work appropriately. my code is like that

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final double itemHeight = (size.width / 2) - 64;
    final double itemWidth = size.width / 2;
    return Container(
      color: Colour.backgroundColor,
      width: double.infinity,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14, horizontal: 20),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(localized(context, 'photos')!, style: getTitleTextStyle),
          EmptyLine(height: 14),
          SizedBox(
              height: (widget.state!.attachments!.length / 2).round() *
                  (itemWidth - 8),
              child: GridView.builder(
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 16),
                itemCount: widget.state!.attachments!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                    _buildImageCard(index, context, itemHeight, itemWidth),
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

P.S (edit) => I added `shrinkWrap: true` to the gridView, everythink works fine

Comment: Possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58248510/flutter-non-scrollable-grid

Comment: thank you, I just added shrinkWrap: true